# OS X Lion launches iTunes when connecting a Bluetooth Headset

Tags: itunes, bluetooth, osx-lion

Is there any way to prevent this? I've disabled the `iTunes Helper` Login Item but iTunes will still start automatically when I connect my Bluetooth Headphones.

Comment: [Couple](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r25350833-Blue-Tooth-Annoyance) of [related](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2570254?start=0&tstart=0) forum [entries](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2621604?start=0&tstart=0). Haven't seen a fix yet -- weird issue.

Comment: You may need to uninstall iTunes.  Many other people have had this problem for years, and none have found solutions. very sorry.

Comment: For me it just started happening in Lion. I've been using BT headphones since Leopard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is completely stupid and seemingly unrelated but it works:

In the **CDs and DVDs** preference pane disable iTunes to launch inserted for **Audio CDs**

your headset is an audio cd you know ;-)

Comment: Definitely stupid, but works! Thanks

Comment: Can't do this in Mavericks. :(

Answer (score 1):

What I did is renaming itunes using

> sudo mv /Applications/iTunes.app /Applications/iTunesBACK.app

But It does ask where is iTunes when you connect the headset. At least after moving the window around, it doesn't nag me anymore.

Comment: Probably the only around this for now...

Comment: In addition to renaming itunes, you can create a "do nothing app" in its place called iTunes.app. On AskDifferent, [here are complete steps](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/98462/40311) to solve this annoying issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out on Mavericks. I did five steps:

Rename the iTunes.app to iTunesclosed.app

Open a blank AppleScript Editor and save a blank window in the Applications folder as an application type (not the default script type) as DoNothing.app

Remove the iTunesHelper from system preferences > users > login items

Connect to the bluetooth speaker it will ask you where is iTunes located? Click browse and point it to the DoNothing.app

(iTunes will still launch when you connect to a bluetooth speaker)

In Finder go to Applications and show package contents on iTunesclosed.app. Inside the MacOS folder there is a unix script called iTunes, i right clicked get info and changed the name to iTunesclosed.

With the first three steps, iTunes still opened whenever I connect to my bluetooth speaker. This last step prevented iTunes from opening.